# Quick way to navigate between Sub Tab pages using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

Guys I'm right now Stack and upset because I can't get it working...I have an MVC application which works well. Only I have a View Page of Many Main Tabs with Sub Tabs (see picture). My question is that: Is it possible to toggle between sub tabs using JS? If yes, then how?
I have tried the following but it's only toggling the Main Tabs and not the Sub tabs once an action is send.
[image]

I tried the following JS:

```
function Edit(url) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        success: function (response) {
            $("#userSubSecondTab").html(response);
            $('ul.nav.nav-tabs a:eq(1)').html('Edit User Record'); 
            $('ul.nav.nav-tabs a:eq(1)').tab('show'); 
        }
    });
}
```

And Main Page Views:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Main tab 1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Main tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Main Tab 3 </a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">Main Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in">@Html.Action("ViewMain1")</div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane in active">@Html.Action("ViewMain2")</div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade in">@Html.Action("ViewMain3")</div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab-pane fade in">@Html.Action("ViewMain4")</div>
</div>
```

Now Sub Tab View

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> List of Users</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
                    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#userSubFirstTab">View All Users</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#userSubSecondTab">Add New </a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="userSubFirstTab" class="tab-pane fade in active">@Html.Action("ViewUsers")</div>
                    <div id="userSubSecondTab" class="tab-pane fade in">@Html.Action("AddOrEditUser")</div>
                </div>
                <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Really I don't know What I am doing wrong? My problem is that when the JS toggle the view, it's changes from the Main Tab View rather than the Sub Tab View (Add User & View User)

How can the JS redirect or toggle the Sub View when ever a Edit button is Click?
I want the view to switch between Add New to View User tab and not from The Main Tab View.
I think It's might be something about the JS but I don't know how to do that.

Please Everyone is welcome with an answer!